# Spring Boot + SPring REST + Swagger + JPA +inmemory H2 DB

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I am working on Spring REST using Spring Boot. I started by hardcoding values to ***DAOService*** as below and everything working fine

```
@Component
public class UserDAOService {

    static List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    static int userCount = 3;

    static {
        users.add(new User("adam", new Date(), 1));
        users.add(new User("eve", new Date(), 2));
        users.add(new User("joe", new Date(), 3));
    }

    public User saveUser(User user) {
        if (user.getId() == null) {
            user.setId(++userCount);
        }
        users.add(user);
        return user;
    }

    public List<User> findAll() {
        System.out.println("finding all users");
        return users;
    }

    public User findOne(int id) {

        for (User user : users) {
            if (user.getId() == id) {
                return user;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But later i tried to integrate JPA and convert bean to entity as below , at first i got error creating bean with name 'documentationpluginsbootstrapper',but was resolved by removing @Configuration annotation from SwaggerConfig class.But later it ended up with another exception ***Error creating bean with name 'repositorySearchController'*** ..*Log is shown at the end*

```
    @ApiModel(description="all details about user")
    @Entity
    public class User {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Integer id ;

        @Size(min=2,max=12,message="username should be atleast 2 characters")
        private String name;
        @Past
        private Date birthDate; 

        public User(String name, Date birthDate, Integer id) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.birthDate = birthDate;
            this.id = id;
        }
        public User() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        } 
//setters and getters    
    }
```

### log:

***org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException***: Error creating bean with name 'repositorySearchController' defined in ...... spring-***data-rest-webmvc-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar***

Need inputs to resolve this.

Comment: please post controller class

Comment: Please share the code of repositorySearchController class

Comment: //@RestController
public class UserResource {

 //@Autowired
 private UserDAOService daoService;

 //@GetMapping(path = "/users")
 public List<User> getUsers() {
  return daoService.findAll();
 }}                  i commented annotationa bcz it was not allowing me to post comment

Comment: Hi @GarimaGupta , repositorySearchController  is in jar  spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar

Comment: @JohnJoe , my controller class is //@RestController public class UserResource { //@Autowired private UserDAOService daoService; //@GetMapping(path = "/users") public List<User> getUsers() { return daoService.findAll(); }}                                                                                                                        i commented annotationa bcz it was not allowing me to post comment

Comment: @spa where you declare repositorySearchController ?

Comment: @JohnJoe i haven't declared  repositorySearchController  , i have UserController 
 annotated with -@RestController,UserDAOService annotated with -@Component and User bean (which i annotated with -@Entity) .And in application.properties i have these two properties added spring.jpa.show_sql=true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

Comment: Hi @JohnJoe  I moved User.java and UserDAOService.java to to package where UserResource.java exists and application is up and running but USER table not created when i checked in http://localhost:8080/h2-console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect to **H2 database** you should add the following properties to `application.properties` file:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
```

and you can access to BD from URL: `http://localhost:8080/h2-console/`

Comment: Still not able to get o/p. Build failed if the Entity(User.java) is placed in different package than that of  Resource(UserResource.java)  but if i placed in same package i am able to connect to db and see changes. But if i moved Entity to different package ,build fails.

Comment: In that case, you should update your question and add details about what is happening now